# Could not restore StateHolder of type org.primefaces.component.resetinput.ResetInputActionListener

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myfaces

I've got very strange error on PrimeFaces application, that I have not seen before.

*Could not restore StateHolder of type `org.primefaces.component.resetinput.ResetInputActionListener` (missing no-args constructor?)*

The class `org.primefaces.component.resetinput.ResetInputActionListener` has actually no no-arg constructor, but it wasn't the problem before... Otherwise no primefaces app would function...

What is the actual cause of that error and how to fix it?

I'm using **PrimeFaces 3.5** with **MyFaces 2.0.7** on **WebSphere 7**.

```
                                 javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not restore StateHolder of type org.primefaces.component.resetinput.ResetInputActionListener (missing no-args constructor?)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at de.datev.commons.web.filter.CharsetEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharsetEncodingFilter.java:54)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not restore StateHolder of type org.primefaces.component.resetinput.ResetInputActionListener (missing no-args constructor?)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1603)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaList.restoreState(_DeltaList.java:251)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1616)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1730)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1386)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1429)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1429)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1429)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1429)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1429)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processRestoreState(UIViewRoot.java:736)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageBase.restoreView(ViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.restoreView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1464)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.primefaces.component.resetinput.ResetInputActionListener
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1345)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1599)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a case in which this issue is occuring?

Comment: It's a very complex view so without the idea why something like that is occuring I have no idea where to search

Comment: [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) -> Tips for trimming :) Will probably help you in getting this issue solved

Comment: It would help to find the workaround, but not the cause of the problem, nor would it help to prevent it in future.

Comment: How would it not help you find the cause of the problem? You could strip your page down to the scenario that causes it. This content would be valuable to anyone trying to help you solve it. Though it's up to you ofcourse ;)

Comment: Removing the p:resetInput from p:commandButton has helped. I've forgotten that I've used them, but when I was writting that code, it was functioning. So the SSCCE principle leads to conclusion: don't use X feature of Y, because it sometimes isn't working....

Comment: Yep, I've come to that conclusion multiple times with Primefaces (on other features). I'd post this issue (along with your case of using both tags) on the Primefaces forum. The developer is very active there.

Comment: Well, the problem is, that p:resetInput caused that problem under some circumstances, and the context is too big now to locate what have changed that behaviour. 
So the solution to that question would be to answer if the ResetInputActionListener should have default constructor, or the MyFaces should not try to find it.

Comment: Well, maybe a default constructor can be added to `ResetInputActionListener`. Provided there are good reasons to do so ofcourse. Nevertheless you'd need to wait for another version in that case.

Answer (score 0):

**p:resetInput** in Primefaces 3.5 is buggy (corrected from 4.0), it lacks a no-args constructor.

Use [Omnifaces ResetInputAjaxActionListener](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/ResetInputAjaxActionListener) instead, or define a custom resetInput method that reuses Primefaces code and call it from your action:

```
public static void resetInputs(String targetIds) {
    ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(Faces.getViewRoot());
    ResetInputActionListener reset = new ResetInputActionListener(Components.createValueExpression(targetIds, String.class));
    reset.processAction(event);
}
```

**Note:** Overriding ResetInputActionListener and adding missing constructor doesn't work because containing component isn't properly restored.